# JAVA JUnit testing using Easymock

Tags: java, junit

`my code is as follows:enter code here

```
   public String createDir(String X, String Y){
    String dirName = null;

    try {
        File dir = new File(X+Y);
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(X+Y));
        File checkPath = new File(path.getParent().toString());
        boolean isDirCreated = dir.mkdir();
        if(isDirCreated){
            dirName = path.getFileName().toString();    
        }else {
            dirName = null;
        }
    }
    catch(SecurityException se){
        //message
    }
    catch(Exception se){
    //message
        dirName = null;
    }
    return dirName; 
}
```

`My JUnit Test Case:
In this test case I have mocked the objects of path,file.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.easymock.Mock;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.Users.Folder.Utilities;



public class UtilitiesTest {
@Mock
Utilities Utils;
@Mock
File dir,checkPath;
@Mock
Path path;


@Test
public void testCreateDir() throws Exception {

    expect(dir).andReturn(new File("C:\\Users\\sasank\\Desktop\\Docs\\Docs_docready"));
    expect(path).andReturn(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\Users\\sasank\\Desktop\\Docs\\Docs_docready"));
    expect(checkPath).andReturn(new File("C:\\Users\\sasank\\Desktop\\Docs"));
    replay(dir,path,checkPath);
    assertEquals(true, isDirCreated); //isDirCreated cannot be resolved to a variable
    verify(dir,path,checkPath);
    assertEquals("Docs_docready", imiUtils.dirName); // dirName cannot be resolved or is not a field
}
```

`dirName is also a boolean type.
what my code does is it creates a new directory in the input directory.

Answer (score 0):

The "expect" method expects a call for a method from an object, which is replaced by returning value when you call the "andRetuns()". It is used for mocking classes/interfaces behaviors and does not process plain values.

For values comparison, you should use "assertEquals()" or, in your case "assertTrue()" methods in JUnit.

Simply do:

```
assertTrue(isDirCreated);
```

or

```
assertEquals(true, isDirCreated);
```

in your tests to verify the condition.

**EDIT: 
Seeing your code and how it behaves, here are some comments:**

1. I think you don't need Mocks;
2. For a better understanding about what Mocks are and how they behave, you should read: http://easymock.org/getting-started.html
3. "isDirCreated" is a local variable and is never visiblie outside of "createDir" method. If you want it visible, you should create an attribute in your class and write a getter instead;
4. A simpler way to do your test is (assuming that "createDir" method is in a class named "Dir". If not, simply replace "Dir" with your current class name):

   ```
   @Test
   public void testCreateDir() throws Exception {
       Dir dir = new Dir();
       String directory = dir.createDir("c:/", "test_dir");
       assertNotNull(directory); // this one checks if your method returned the correct path
       File file = new File(directory);
       assertTrue(file.exists()); // this one checks if your method created correctly you directory
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I use assert it gives me an error isDirCreated cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @sasank could you please post your full code (class + tests) so I can help a little more?

Comment: can anyone answer to my question?